# Why is the Visual Studio debugger skipping valid lines?

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a VB.NET program in Visual Studio 2017. There is a patch of code that the debugger skips completely over every time. I have rewritten it a dozen times trying to make it work. Code optimization is turned off. I have tried deleting every single file in the Solution folder and subfolders except for the source files and rebuilding from scratch. No change. Google hasn't given me a solution.

[image]
In this case, `ClientList` has two elements, so the `.Count` is 2.
I want to traverse it from the last element to the first, so I use a for loop on line 209.
While debugging, I verify the count is 2, so the debugger should work its way through the for loop twice. But after line 209, it jumps straight to line 228.

I included the second loop for comparison because it always debugs fine, even though it's doing the same thing, iterating through the elements of `ClientList`.

Can anyone solve this for me? I've spent most of the day on this and can't get any further until I have a solution.

Comment: If you get the solution from MatSnow's suggestion, you could mark his reply as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add `Step -1` to the `For`-statement and it should work as expected.

```
For ClientIndex As Integer = ClientList.Count -1 To 0 Step -1
```

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement):

> The default value of step is 1.

Means, without `Step -1` the value of the loop counter is incremented and thus the loop never runs because `1` (`ClientList.Count-1`) is already greater than `0`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the syntax clarification. I updated my code and it now works.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.Please help to mark it as answer which will help more people to find it @jbbarnes